# Can I link directly to an email in a user's zimbra webmail client?

Tags: email-server, webmail, zimbra

I'm using Zimbra's handy RESTful xml API (http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/ZCS_6.0:Zimbra_REST_API_Reference:Get_Folder) to pull down important emails from a user's email account.  I'd like to make them link back to the message on their webmail client, but I can't find the url I'd use.

I've got all the data from the xml feed; I'm just looking for the format I'd use to link back to the full message.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/ZCS_6.0:Zimbra_REST_API_Reference:Get_Item you need to know the item id, as in example:

> Retrieve the mail message (with id 288) as MIME RFC822 format: 
>   http://localhost:7070/home/john.doe/?id=288

Comment: If you want to load the email directly into the Zimbra interface, you have to know the id, and optionally to authenticate with auth=qp&zauthtoken=<your auth token>. Then you can open the email by doing the following : yourzimbraserver/?id=1234&auth=qp&zauthtoken=your_zauthtoken